# Selecting the option chosen in a discrete-choice experiment in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset, from a choice experiment:

```
   ID task opt q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8
1   1    1   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
2   1    1   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
3   1    1   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
4   1    2   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
5   1    2   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
6   1    2   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
7   1    3   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
8   1    3   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
9   1    3   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
10  1    4   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
11  1    4   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
12  1    4   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
13  1    5   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
14  1    5   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
15  1    5   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
16  1    6   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
17  1    6   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
18  1    6   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
19  1    7   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
20  1    7   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
21  1    7   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
22  1    8   1  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
23  1    8   2  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
24  1    8   3  2  3  1  2  2  1  2  1
```

Meaning individual 1 (`ID`) was asked 8 questions (`task`), each of which had 3 options (`opt`) she could choose from. The remaining columns (`q1...q8`) reflect the option she chose in each of the choice tasks. So, she chose option 2 on question 1 and, again, option 2 on question 7.

I'm looking to turn it into a dataset that looks like this instead:

```
   ID task opt chosen
1   1    1   1  FALSE
2   1    1   2  TRUE 
3   1    1   3  FALSE
4   1    2   1  FALSE
5   1    2   2  FALSE
6   1    2   3  TRUE 
7   1    3   1  TRUE 
8   1    3   2  FALSE
9   1    3   3  FALSE
...
22  1    8   1  TRUE
23  1    8   2  FALSE
24  1    8   3  FALSE
```

In other words, a new column (`chosen`) reflects `TRUE` if that particular option was chosen in that particular question, and `FALSE` otherwise.

I've tried all forms of `melt` and `reshape` and `cast` but I've come up empty.

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain the first row of your output? Where is the question number?

Comment: @onyambu, as in the text between the two datasets, `task` is the question number, and `opt` is each choice in the question. So, question 1 (`task == 1`) has three choices the respondent can pick from (`opt == 1:3`), and, in this case, has chosen the second option (`q1 == 2`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first `pivot_longer` columns `q1` to `q8`, then `filter` for "q" number that matches the `task` column. Then set the `chosen` column to `TRUE` if the `value` column matches the `opt` column. Finally removes the newly created columns.

Update: Credit to @Sotos for improving the answer. Now we set the logical column `chosen` directly from the comparison of `value` to `opt` without an `if_else`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(q1:q8, names_to = "Q") %>% 
  filter(task == gsub("q", "", Q)) %>% 
  mutate(chosen = value == opt) %>%
  select(-Q, -value)

   ID task opt chosen
1   1    1   1  FALSE
2   1    1   2   TRUE
3   1    1   3  FALSE
4   1    2   1  FALSE
5   1    2   2  FALSE
6   1    2   3   TRUE
7   1    3   1   TRUE
8   1    3   2  FALSE
9   1    3   3  FALSE
10  1    4   1  FALSE
11  1    4   2   TRUE
12  1    4   3  FALSE
13  1    5   1  FALSE
14  1    5   2   TRUE
15  1    5   3  FALSE
16  1    6   1   TRUE
17  1    6   2  FALSE
18  1    6   3  FALSE
19  1    7   1  FALSE
20  1    7   2   TRUE
21  1    7   3  FALSE
22  1    8   1   TRUE
23  1    8   2  FALSE
24  1    8   3  FALSE
```

Comment: This `if_else(value == opt, T, F)` is simply this `value == opt`. No need for the ifelse

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for your comment! I also thought about this when I write code like this. But I do think that an `if_else` statement might be clearer to readers especially if they are new

Comment: No. I strongly disagree. It's bad practise vulnerable to all kinds of errors

Comment: @Sotos May I know why would it be vulnerable to errors? The expression (`value == opt`) is identical whether it's in an `if_else` or not. So if it'd give error in an `if_else`, should it also gives error in `value == opt`?

Comment: What you said, plus many others. One small mistake and you get this, `ifelse(5 == 5, F, T)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution with `rowwise()` and `c_across()`, where you don't even need to transform data to long form.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(chosen = c_across(q1:q8)[task] == opt) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(!q1:q8)

# A tibble: 24 × 4
      ID  task   opt chosen
   <int> <int> <int> <lgl> 
 1     1     1     1 FALSE 
 2     1     1     2 TRUE  
 3     1     1     3 FALSE 
 4     1     2     1 FALSE 
 5     1     2     2 FALSE 
 6     1     2     3 TRUE  
 7     1     3     1 TRUE  
 8     1     3     2 FALSE 
 9     1     3     3 FALSE 
10     1     4     1 FALSE 
11     1     4     2 TRUE  
12     1     4     3 FALSE 
13     1     5     1 FALSE 
14     1     5     2 TRUE  
15     1     5     3 FALSE 
16     1     6     1 TRUE  
17     1     6     2 FALSE 
18     1     6     3 FALSE 
19     1     7     1 FALSE 
20     1     7     2 TRUE  
21     1     7     3 FALSE 
22     1     8     1 TRUE  
23     1     8     2 FALSE 
24     1     8     3 FALSE
```